# Servlet for file upload - contentType returning 'none' when file extension in CAPS - why?

Tags: image, jsp, servlets, image-processing, file-upload

My Java Servlet processes a file sent through a form on my JSP page. I want to accept image files only. So first thing the servlet does is check to see if the content-type is that of an image.

To check the content-type, I use :

```
File f = new File(fieldValue); // Create a FileItem object to access the file.

// Get content type by filename.
 String contentType = getServletContext().getMimeType(f.getName());                               
if(contentType == null) contentType = "none";

if(contentType.startsWith("image")) {
   //call methods - resize photo
}
```

The problem? It will accept an image file, so long as the extension (.jpg, .png, etc) is NOT capitalized. When the file extension is in CAPS (ex. myphoto.JPG) the call to `getServletContext().getMimeType(f.getName())` returns `null`.

My servlet changes the entire file name to lowercase letters, but that still doesn't make a difference if the file is submitted with capital letters for its extension.

What can I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the API,

> The MIME type is determined by the configuration of the servlet container, and may be specified in a web application deployment descriptor.

If you are using Tomcat, then look at Tomcat/conf/web.xml   That is where Tomcat has it's Default MIME Type Mappings.  But, as the API says, you can add mappings to your web app's web.xml file.

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>JPG</extension>
    <mime-type>image/jpeg</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using Tomcat. I followed your instructions, updated the web.xml file for the capitalized extension types, and now things work as they should. Thank you for the response...and correct answer!